# HAProxy - limit number of connections per second to backend based on Authorization HTTP header

Tags: frontend, backend, haproxy

In some cases, users can generate hundreds connection attempts per second to the server.
I want to limit the number of connections coming to the internal server to 1 connection per user per second.
Hundreds connection can comes from same IP but some of them has different Authorization string in HTTP header. So I try to accept connections from users with same IP, but different Authorization string. But my config doesn't work. HAProxy accept all connections. Where is mistake?

```
global
 maxconn 1000
 daemon

defaults
  log global
  timeout client 5s
  timeout connect 5s
  timeout server 5s
    
frontend HAproxy
     bind *:5000-5200
     tcp-request inspect-delay 10s
     stick-table type string size 10k expire 30s store http_req_rate(1s)
     tcp-request content track-sc0 hdr(Authorization)
     http-request deny deny_status 429 if {sc_http_req_rate(0) gt 1 }
     default_backend Server1
    
backend Server1
     mode tcp
     balance roundrobin
     server internal-server1 172.16.1.1
     server internal-server2 172.16.1.2
```